# Regex matching comma separated lists with a fixed length?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a comma separated list like the following:

```
element1,element2,element3;element4,element5,element6,element7;element8,element9;
```

Each element can be **any text** but no comma within an element.

What I hope to do is, match the element list with a specific length.

For example, if I input 4, the code will match 4 elements list, it will output **element4,element5,element6,element7**.

If I specify 2 , it will output **element8,element9**.

Is this possible?

Comment: In what programming language do you want to achieve this ?

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski Hi I am writing in javascript (nodejs). And this list is in an txt file.

Comment: Why `element8,element9` and not `element2,element3` or `element5,element9`?

Comment: @Toto Hi my list is separated by semi-colon; except for the first one. and "element2,element3" in "element1,element2,element3"  starts with a comma before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Regex should work. The number 2 is the number of ',' you are searching for.

```
(;|^)(\w*)((,\w*){2});
```

You can evaluate Regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com) in a visual and self teaching way.

Comment: Reread the question "Each element can be any text", `\w` matches only word characters.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Regex for this.

Using your input String, you can just use a combination of split() and find() to do what you want. For example:

```
function findInString(str, length) {
  return str
    .split(";") // split at semicolons
    .map(elem => elem.split(",")) // split at commas to make an Array of Arrays
    .find(arr => arr.length === length)  // Array length === input length
    .join(",") // make into a String again (if you want to)
}
```

If you want to account for errors though (e.g. asking for a negative length) you'll have to account for these in the `find` bit, or join separately. For example:

```
function findInString(str, length) {
  const res = str
    .split(";")
    .map(elem => elem.split(","))
    .find(arr => arr.length === length) 

  if(res) {
    return res.join(",")
  } else {
    return ""
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm thinking about regex mainly because that txt file is very large, probably will create 10000 elements when I do the map. But I'll definitely compare this with regex to see if regex will be faster.